# Why is "$\text{not }(f'>0)$" not logically equivalent to $f' \le 0$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Recently, I was trying to solve a proof of the type $P \implies Q$ with $Q$ representing the statement $f'>0$. I tried to solve this by contradiciton and rewrote it as $P \text{ and not }Q$ is false. Here I thought that $\text{ not} f'>0$ was equivalent to $f' \le 0$ but was told I was wrong in thinking that, can anyone explain to me why?

Comment: $f'$ could be undefined. Or maybe the validity of the statement is considered on an interval. $f'>0$ would mean for all x on some interval. The logical opposite would be "there exists at least one $x$ on the interval for which $f'>0$ is false"

Comment: So would the 'not' version be "there exists $x$ such that $f(x)\le 0$ (comment I was resoinding to seems to have been deleted)

Comment: Try $f(x)=\sin x$.

Comment: @HungaryGoose that would be more correct, but there could also exist x values for which $f'$ is not defined. Many functions are not differentiable everywhere. It is safer to say exists an $x$ for which $f'>0$ is not true.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $D$ be the domain of $f'$. Then $f'>0$ means $(\forall x\in D):f'(x)>0$. Therefore, $\neg f'>0$ means $(\exists x\in D):f'(x)\leqslant0$, whereas $f'\leqslant 0$ means $(\forall x\in D):f'(x)\leqslant0$.

Comment: Could also exist $x$ where $f'$ undefined.